# Bulk Database processing in liferay

Tags: mysql, hibernate, liferay-6

I need to insert 200k records into MySQL database, using liferay service builder.

Currently it is taking 20+ minutes to process.

Is there a way to optimize this? I want to reduce processing time by 40-50%

Bulk processing and multiple values insertion is not feasible as it will require changes in configuration.

Below is the service.xml file

```
<entity name="table1" 
     table="iguv_table1" data-source="defaultdbDataSource"
   local-service="true" remote-service="false" session-factory="defaultdbSessionFactory"
    tx-manager="defaultdbTransactionManager">

    <!-- PK Fields -->

    <column name="orderNo" type="String" primary="true" />

    <!-- Group instance -->

    <column name="groupId" type="long" />

    <!-- Audit Fields -->

    <column name="companyId" type="long" />
    <column name="createrUserId" type="long" />
    <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="lastUpdaterUserId" type="long" />
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="approverUserId" type="long" />

    <!-- Other Fields -->

    <column name="rmsOrderNo" type="String" />
    <column name="supplier" type="String" />
    <column name="currencyCode" type="String" />
    <column name="terms" type="String" />
    <column name="notBeforeDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="notAfterDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="otbEowDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="dept" type="int" />
    <column name="status" type="String" />
    <column name="exchangeRate" type="double" />
    <column name="includeOnOrdInd" type="String" />
    <column name="orderDetailsId" type="String" />
    <column name="origInd" type="String" />
    <column name="ediPoInd" type="String" />
    <column name="preMarkInd" type="String" />


    <column name="supplierName" type="String" />
    <column name="hasNewItems" type="boolean" />

    <column name="retryCount" type="int"></column>
    <column name="successfullyPostedToRMS" type="boolean" convert-null="false"></column>

    <finder name="rmsOrderNo" return-type="PurchaseOrder">
        <finder-column name="rmsOrderNo" />
    </finder>
    <finder name="notSyncedPurchaseOrders" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="successfullyPostedToRMS"></finder-column>
        <finder-column name="status"></finder-column>
    </finder>

</entity>
```